# Printing array of multi-digit elements in reverse order in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

How to print an array of elements in reverse order not just single digit number but also multi-digit numbers.

```
[2, 5, 6 7]
```

It should print the array elements in reverse order as `7 6 5 2` by following a space for each number.

I  already wrote the code for this.

```
   puts "Enter the array elements"
    arr = gets.strip
    arr = arr.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
    x = arr.reverse_each {|f| }
    z = x.join(" ")
    print z.reverse
```

That is cool with single digit numbers, how can I reverse the multi-digit numbers in an array of inputs given by the user input like:

```
[45, 76, 87 ] # this should reverse the array as `87 76 45`


[556, 674, 878 ] # this should reverse the array as `878 674 556`
[8797, 7347, 9374 ] # this should reverse the array as `9374 7374 8797`
```

Comment: What is `n`? It is never used in the above code.

Comment: `n` is just used to know many elements does the array contain. However, I didn't use `n` in the above code. Maybe I should remove that code.!

Comment: I don't have time to post an answer, but here's a hint: two Ruby core classes have a `reverse` method, `Array` and `String`. You are using the latter one.

Comment: `puts gets.strip.split(' ').map(&:to_i).reverse.inspect`

Comment: Thanks for the hit. Am getting the same output `[34, 54,76]  => [67, 45, 43]' with both `reverse` methods `reverse_each` and `reverse` which is not I want.

Comment: The first expression is invalid.

Comment: `gets.split.reverse.join(' ')` seems to do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like one-liners:

```
gets.strip.split(' ').reverse.join(' ')
```

This will take the input `1 2 3 45 678 9` and convert it to `"9 678 45 3 2 1"`

Comment: #Optmized code. This worked like a charm!. Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't it be `9 876 54 3 2 1` ? instead of your posted output  `9 678 45 3 2 1`

Comment: No. It would be `9 876 54 3 2 1` if you reversed the string. In my solution, `reverse` is being called on the output of `split` which is an array. This reverses the order of the elements in the array, but not the content of the elements themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Input: `[8797, 7347, 9374 ]`

Output: `"9374 7374 8797"`

```
arr = gets.chomp
arr = arr.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
x = arr.reverse.join(' ')
print x
```

Use `reverse` and `join` chained and it should return a `String` type that joined your reversed array.

Comment: Please next time use “edit” to modify/update/correct the already posted answer, not just delete the old one and post the new version as a separate answer. Plus, the reference to [`Array#reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse) was helpful.

Comment: @mudasobwa Sorry about that, will definitely do that next time

Comment: @philip yoo, Perfect solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Packer hey check out Scott's solution as well. I realized you don't need to change them to `Integer` type, but rather just split, reverse, then join again. :)